How to make a custom bottom navbar with a curve?
How to make a custom navbar with a curve like this? What i'm trying to make a navbar with  a curve like this, when that particular navbar item is selected. I have used a container now Which will be the better way to create this?!
update:
I don't need animation. i need only one element to be popped like this.



You can achieve your result using the convex_bottom_bar package.
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';

Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
    items: [
      TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.map, title: 'Discovery'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.add, title: 'Add'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.message, title: 'Message'),
      TabItem(icon: Icons.people, title: 'Profile'),
    ],
    onTap: (int i) => print('click index=$i'),
  )
);

